# Why did the alien's head twitch?

Tags: riverworld

The [2003 TV adaptation of Riverworld](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0310952/) features an alien character named Monat. In most scenes where he is seen, his head constantly twitches.

**Does that twitching have a meaning in-universe, or is it an out-of-universe artefact?**

That is,

- Was the twitching done deliberately to portray a feature of the alien's biology?

  - As I haven't read the books, is that maybe even a feature explained in there?
- Or was the twitching involuntary, due to some sort of an illness of the actor [Brian Moore](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1094001/)?

Comment: I tried watching it once, [but I was so underwhelmed by, well, pretty much everything](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/DarthWiki/SoBadItsHorrible) that I gave up on it pretty quickly.

Comment: @JoeL.: I quite enjoyed it. After watching, I was actually disappointed the series that this was the pilot for never came to being.

Comment: Monat in the TV show looked nothing like Monat in the books. I imagine the actor just wanted to look more alien.
It would be fun if some TV outlet would take another stab at making a Riverworld series, only taking a longer arc, like maybe one book for each season.